# Space Issues in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm running an **Azure Function** under the **Consumption Plan**, and every so often I get a bunch of errors around no space in the Function... Errors such as:

> Exception while executing function: PdfToImages. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'req'. mscorlib: Error while copying content to a stream. mscorlib: There is not enough space on the disk.

I read that there is a limitation of 1GB or memory, but I dont seem to be using that and I deleted all the files I use after each call.

> The storage limit is the total content size in temporary storage across all apps in the same App Service plan. Consumption plan uses Azure Files for temporary storage.

What seems even more confusion is that some calls make it throught and don't have space issues and also that once I start seeing the issues I restart the Function and all the calls work.

Here is a sample volume screenshot...

[image]

Can someone please enlight me on how exactly disk space is handled...

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits Storage limit: 1GB in AppService Plan. "Consumption plan uses Azure Files for temporary storage."

Comment: Thanks @silent and yes, I should have space in the Storage Account... and it still doesnt answer why subsequent calls work and why calls work after a restart

Comment: how big are the requests you are making against your function? I assume we are talking about http? and how many (per second/minute/etc) of those?

Comment: Yes they are HTTP requests ... I've added a screenshot so you can see how long they take... basically I'm running  <20 a minute and they are a couple Mbs each..... I started having issues when the volume increased

Comment: Hm I guess it could be something in you app logic how the pdf2image functions that you use, use temp disk space. Try to debug and profile this locally

Comment: I've had this running for over a year... and when running locally I have no issues... I make sure I dispose all the objects I create and delete any folder I might create... I've checked the FileShare in the storage account and its basically empty.... how can I get visibility into the issue? @silent

Comment: Guess you should open a ticket with the azure support then

Comment: @pmeyer did you get any insights on this? Currently I have an Azure Function (Python) running on docker that downloads a file, applies a transformation, uploads the file and removes the downloaded file. The removal of the local file is in a finally statement and checked with an if path exists so I am pretty sure the local files get deleted. However, the disk space usage keeps on rising. When I restart the Function the disk space is freed. Checking disk space via `df -h` command in kudu.

Comment: sorry @Jorn.Beyers.... I don't think I ever got any positive feedback ... but I believe the issue resolved itself... Perhaps Azure fixed the issue

Comment: too bad, thanks for the response though!